# How to use Firebase (or Firestore) as an intermediary between a desktop app and an external API endpoint?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions, desktop-application

I have a desktop app that will be distributed to users, and part of its code (which the user might be able to access) has to perform an API call to a third-party web service. However, this requires the API keys to be embedded into the source code, which causes some obvious security issues.

The main solution I've found while researching on the subject is to have a backend server between the user and the third-party API endpoint. So, I've been looking into Firebase for a while and it *seems* that this solution can be implemented using Firestore and Cloud Functions.

But, I wasn't able to find any clear examples that achieve something like this, and since I have no previous experience with Firebase or just backend programming in general, I would like to know if I'm on the right track and get more details about how to get it done, or if there are better alternatives for solving this issue. Any input is appreciated, thx.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the firebase cloud functions as you mentioned. Your desktop application will be communicating with the cloud function - simple API call. Here you can find examples how to implement and deploy functions and test it locally https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/get-started. Your cloud function will hold the API keys (it is backend so it will be secure if you dont expose it explicitly. Also the backend to backend communication is considered as secure). Finally, this cloud function will call the third party service and return some data back to the desktop app if needed. So you are on the right track, that is how the design should look like. If you need some help with cloud functions, you can also contact me directly.